# Illegal state exception when querying MediaStrore.Images

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am getting a IllegalStateException when I run the following code:

```
Cursor imageCursor=getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA},MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME+"=?" ,new String[]{imageTitle},null);
                        imageCursor.moveToFirst();
                        String imageData=imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                        Long imageSize=imageCursor.getLong(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.SIZE));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(imageSize), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong_native(Native Method)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:380)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:108)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getLong(CursorWrapper.java:127)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.messageHider.viewImageThumb$1.onClick(viewImageThumb.java:93)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-12 10:49:27.426: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error is at:

```
Long imageSize=imageCursor.getLong(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.SIZE));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include SIZE in your query projection(the second param in the content resolvers query method).

its MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE i believe.

Comment: Thanx I think I waz too tired. Thanx alot.